# Multiple self-referential has_many :through associations in Rails 4.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I'm writing some code that uses multiple self-referential models, that I'd like to be able to match up using a join table as they are related through it.

The models look like

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :students, through: :appointments
  has_many :teachers, through: :appointments
end
```

Appointment.rb:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, class_name: User
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: User
end
```

Unfortunately, the query generated by Rails is:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "appointments" ON "users"."id" = "appointments"."student_id" WHERE "appointments"."user_id" = $1
```

Which throws an error, because Appointment does not have a user_id parameter.

I've already tried specifying the `foreign_key` option, but this did nothing. Any other ways I could solve this elegantly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: “…the query generated by Rails…” — For what call? What did you do to get this query? You didn't specify, but it would make it easier to understand at a glance what call you're trying.

Comment: I tried `User.first.students`.

Comment: can you show your attempt to specify the foreign key option?

Comment: @maxpleaner Like so: 

`has_many :students, through: :appointments, foreign_key: :student_id`
Analogously for the has_many :teachers association.

Comment: maybe try adding the foreign key option on the belongs_to associations

Comment: @maxpleaner I tried that, too. Unfortunately none of that seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve it. The has_many that the has_many :through is based on, has to have the foreign_key option set. The code became:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments_as_student, foreign_key: :student_id, class_name: Appointment
  has_many :appointments_as_teacher, foreign_key: :teacher_id, class_name: Appointment

  has_many :students, through: :appointments_as_teacher
  has_many :teachers, through: :appointments_as_student
end
```

Thank you everyone for your efforts.